# SSH known_hosts file adds different ssh-rsa code when I want to propagate key to other environment - cause of being unable to connect w/o password?

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, connection

I already have set up SSH connection between few hosts, EACH of them has THE SAME code in known_hosts file, and for each of them the same authorized_keys file is used without any issues. However, when I want to add my next environment following message pops up:

```
The authenticity of host  can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added  (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

After typing "yes" it creates a new entry in known_hosts file, but with other code than rest of the environments. After, I am asked for password, why? (authorized_keys - same as in every other env is propagated to this host too...).

What might be wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're not talking to the host you think you are.

Comment: I am, if I type the password manually, I connect to this host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that it will somehow not work when you have too many permissions on your home directory on the target server. After setting it to be chmod 700 ssh connection works without password

Comment: Yes, `authorized_keys` must be secure, otherwise you have a security risk, because other users can know which keys you allow. `ssh` won't let you login with an insecure setup, and this is the most common pitfall for new users trying to key key authentication working. What about the issue in your question concerning the hosts RSA key and the `known_hosts` file? Was there really a problem or not really?

Comment: that was not an issue, known_hosts contains DSA host keys of SSH servers accessed by the user, and they can be different. I generated new rsa key and now each entry for each host in known_hosts is unique